# Calling method from another class in Activity returns null

Tags: java, android

I have 2 classes, the one is the Location and the second one the MainActivity, what i want to do is get the Latitude in the the Activity Class , using a method from the Location Class , below is the Location class :

```
public class locac implements LocationListener {
    public Context Ctx;
    private final Context context;

    public locac (Context context) {
        this.context=Ctx;
    }

    public int GetLat() {
        LocationManager manag;
        manag=(LocationManager)Ctx.getSystemService(Ctx.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location alfa=manag.getLastKnownLocation(manag.GPS_PROVIDER);
        return (int) (alfa.getLatitude());
    }
```

and here is the part of the MainActivity class

```
locac nova=new locac(this.m);
int latitu=nova.GetLat();
Context m;
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), latitu, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

the error i get is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.alarma.locac.GetLat(locac.java:71)
```

i guess the the Context returns null, but can't understand why

P.S

i am adding the full Activity class :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static final String content="test";
public static final Integer kom=2;
 Context m;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


dbadapter mkola=new dbadapter(MainActivity.this);
mkola.openToWrite();


locac nova=new locac(MainActivity.this);
int latitu=nova.GetLat();

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
        latitu, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


mkola.insert(content);










}



}
```

Comment: What's `this.m`? Give variables a decent name, not `m`. And btw you should read [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

Comment: @Nfear Thank you for your edit. It was a MESS!

Answer (score 2):

In your constructor, the line:

```
this.context=Ctx;
```

does nothing because `Ctx` and `this.context` refer both to the instance variables and hence are `null` when you're creating your object (default value for an object).

It should be :

```
private final Context context; //remove this line
public Context Ctx;


public locac (Context context){
    this.Ctx = context;
}
```

Also be aware that `getLastKnownLocation` can also returns `null`.

P.S :Try to respect naming conventions.

Comment: @m0skit0 No because he explicitely using `this.` so it refers to the field and not the constructor parameter. And the assignment was swapped anyway.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, i made the changes , but the program still crashes with teh NullPointer at GetLat

Comment: @user2557930 As I said `getLaskKnownLocation` can return null. What is the line where the error is thrown? And is `this.m` not null?

Comment: ok i added requestLocationUpdates before getLastKnownLocation, and i have the coordinates set in the emulator, but still same error

Comment: the same one, still getLat gets NullPointer , here it is  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.example.alarma.locac.GetLat(locac.java:75)

Comment: @user2557930 Is the line 75 `manag=(LocationManager)Ctx.getSystemService(Ctx.LOCATION_SERVICE);` ? If yes, it means that `this.m` is null.

Comment: thats correct, this is the line, why woudl this.m be null, and is ther another way of passing the context from Locac class ?

Comment: Is the `Local` class an activity? And it seems that `Context m;` is not initialized.

Comment: no the local class is a standart class and does not inherit from any of the Context sub-classes (activiy,Service etc )

Comment: @user2557930 And do you create a Local object in an Activity? What is the constructor of your Local object? Otherwise you could pass getApplicationContext() in your locac constructor.

Comment: i have listed the Constructor of the Locac class and i initialize the object into the Activity with locac nova=new locac(this.m);

Comment: @user2557930 In your MainActivity, why don't you do ? `locac nova=new locac(MainActivity.this);`?

Comment: @user2557930 Could you post the full code of your MainActivity class ? (in pastebin is fine).

Comment: i apologize , its saved now

Comment: @user2557930 Check if manag is not null. I highly suspect that it's null here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any initializing for Ctx.

```
public Context Ctx;

public locac (Context context){
  this.context=Ctx;
}
```